# Is there a keyboard short-cut to switch IIS manager between Feature and Content view?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, iis, iis-7

Is there a keyboard short-cut to switch IIS manager between Feature and Content view?

I prefer to keep the hands on the keyboard, rather than grab the mouse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find out any keyboard-shortcut to do that (see [IIS introduction page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771124(v=ws.10).aspx)), but you can use the right click menu button, which has the same function with right click mouse. This button on the right side of right <kbd>Window</kbd> button, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> if you don't have such, e.g. on a laptop

Key sequence:

- Use <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> to select your site
- Hit <kbd>Menu</kbd> button, then <kbd>Up</kbd> to select `Switch to Feature/Content view`
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move among panels. This way can keep your hand away of using mouse.

Comment: Excellent, didn't think of the right click menu ... FYI, your response assumes I was using a standard keyboard. In my case it's a laptop ... I have to use the Shift + F10